# NSUserDefaults setObject method causes the app to crash in ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6, nsuserdefaults

I am having an app in which I am passing some data between viewControllers with NSUserDefaults.

This is the code below I am using.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:selectedLists forKey:UserID];
```

Where **selectedLists** is **NSMutableArray** and UserID is **NSString**.

This code works fine until ios7 and xCode5.

Since I have updated xCode6 and now I am using ios8, my app works fine with xCode 6 and ios 7.1 but the app crashes when I run the app in ios8 devices with the error below.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a027060'
```

I just don't understand what is the problem here.

If anyone has faced this problem with ios8 then please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Value of **selectedLists**

```
    {
        CardFace = Word;
        ImportFlag = Import;
        ListID = 1;
        ListName = "Adjectives - Appearance";
        QuizBy = Definition;
        UserID = 1;
    }
```

and UserId is 1.

**EDITED**

```
 *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x06a24df6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03ac8a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x06a2ca75 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x069759c7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x0697558e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
        5   CoreFoundation                      0x068df30f CFStringGetLength + 143
        6   CoreFoundation                      0x069de510 _CFPrefsEncodeKeyValuePairIntoMessage + 64
        7   CoreFoundation                      0x06a275cf -[CFPrefsPlistSource sendMessageSettingValue:forKey:] + 111
        8   CoreFoundation                      0x06954f3a -[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_setValue:forKey:] + 250
        9   CoreFoundation                      0x06954e22 -[CFPrefsSource setValue:forKey:] + 82
        10  CoreFoundation                      0x06954dc3 ___CFPreferencesSetValueWithContainer_block_invoke + 51
        11  CoreFoundation                      0x0690ef0a +[CFPrefsSource withSourceForIdentifier:user:byHost:container:perform:] + 1274
        12  CoreFoundation                      0x06954d61 _CFPreferencesSetValueWithContainer + 225
        13  CoreFoundation                      0x06a0aa62 _CFPreferencesSetAppValueWithContainer + 66
        14  Foundation                          0x0347f53f -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 59
        15  Foundation                          0x0353eeba -[NSUserDefaults(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 68
        16  Vocab                               0x000eaecc Vocab + 720588
        17  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03ade7cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
        18  UIKit                               0x022a079d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
        19  UIKit                               0x022a072f -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
        20  UIKit                               0x023d3a16 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
        21  UIKit                               0x023d3e33 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
        22  UIKit                               0x023d309d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
        23  UIKit                               0x022f0aba -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
        24  UIKit                               0x022f1595 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791
        25  UIKit                               0x022b6aa9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
        26  UIKit                               0x022c68de _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
        27  UIKit                               0x0229b079 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
        28  CoreFoundation                      0x069487bf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
        29  CoreFoundation                      0x0693e2cd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
        30  CoreFoundation                      0x0693d828 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
        31  CoreFoundation                      0x0693d1ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
        32  CoreFoundation                      0x0693cfdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        33  GraphicsServices                    0x0436424f GSEventRunModal + 192
        34  GraphicsServices                    0x0436408c GSEventRun + 104
        35  UIKit                               0x0229ee16 UIApplicationMain + 1526
        36  Vocab                               0x0004c9bc Vocab + 72124
        37  libdyld.dylib                       0x03ee6ac9 start + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

**Edited**
On my tableview's didselect method...

```
UserID = [[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"UserID"];
```

where **users** is an array.

Comment: What kind of object type are selectedLists and UserID?

Comment: I suggest you set an exception breakpoint or check the stack trace to confirm which line it is actually crashing on

Comment: Also, NSUserDefaults is probably not the most efficient way to pass data between objects anyway - `NSNotificationCenter` is a better choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the **UserID** type because crash is not related with changing `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray`.

You must be confusing NSNumber with NSString on your userID:

Change your code and instead of userID use the variable userIDString

```
NSString userIDString;

//If UserID is class of NSNumber turn its value to NSString
if ([UserID isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) 
{ 
    userIDString = [UserID stringValue]; 
} 
else 
    userIDString = UserID ;
```

Comment: @Manthan you can't store custom objects's NSMutableArray to userDefaults. You need to represent it as NSData. Ill edit my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks... but it works for ios6 and ios7 then why this problem comes only for ios8?

Comment: I don't know how you really passed these custom objects to NSUserDefaults, but this is a well-known issue that you can't pass the objects to NSUserDefaults. If you have NSDictionaries on you array than the logic changes.

Comment: Actually i got an existing project and i am making some modifications so i am not aware some changes made by other developer. So sorry for that.

Comment: When i write this [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:selectedLists] forKey:UserID]; the app still crashes.

Comment: You need to add the <NSCoding> to your custom class. For example @interface CustomObject : NSObject <NSCoding>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62737/discussion-between-eridb-and-manthan).

Comment: :Yeah there was a problem with database. I solved my problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

During runtime `UserId` is probably of type `NSNumber`, even if in your code it is typed `NSString`.

Check how `UserId` is created. Use the debugger to check the runtime type.

The newly posted code shows that your retrieve the `UserId` from the `users` array which probably consists of dictionaries. In those dictionaries there's a value for the key `UserID`. It depends on how the array of dictionaries is created (json deserialization?) but it seems that the type of object referred to by the `UserID` key is a number type, not a string. So all you have to do is convert this number into a string:

```
UserID = [[[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"UserID"] stringValue];
```

Now your key is always a string.

Comment: yes user id is 1 so it takes it is nsnumber but takes it as nsstring

Comment: @Manthan The key can't be an `NSNumber`, it must be an `NSString`. Again, check how the key is created and convert it to a string, if necessary.

Comment: Ok i'll try and let you know.

Comment: I have taken userid as nsstring but it returns nsnumber then what should i do?

Comment: The bug is in code you did not post yet. As I said, check the code that creates the `UserId` object. Where do you get it from? Add this information/code to your question or we won't be able to post a solution.

Comment: Try and replace this `UserID = [[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"UserID"];`  with `UserID = [NSString stringWithFormat:[[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"UserID"]intValue];`
If it doesn't work, user integerValue (or any other autocompletion that is integer related)
UserID should now be a string.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: Thanks. I solved this with your help. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think can't store `NSMutableArrays` in `NSUserDefaults` since iOS8 (according to different posts).  Try casting it into an array before (or create a new one).

Like this for example :

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:selectedLists];
```

And store `arr` in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: You can store NSMutableArray to NSUserDefaults but when you get it, the array is not a mutable object, so you have to create new one.

Comment: I've had the exact same crash in an app and using NSArray fixed my problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029704/nsuserdefaults-pause-crash-on-ios8
Apparently this is new to iOS8, maybe?

Comment: Same issue here when IOS 8 released (NSMutable > NSUserDefaults) and replace mymutable by a non mutable array solve my problem...

Comment: I just ran a test where I added an NSMutableArray to NSUserDefaults and retrieved it as an array - no problems

Comment: Well i can't say more than what i've said before, i've had an app that stopped crashing by just changing the mutablearray to a non-mutable one, and apparently i'm not the only one. But maybe this is just fixing another problem that isn't the array type but something else. I hear you, this is strange/weird though.

Comment: I tried it too in Xcode 6.1 GM, works perfectly by adding NSMutableArray.

Comment: My array had only strings - it seems more likely it is related to the incorrect storage of custom objects

Comment: @Zil: Thanks for your help too... +1 for you to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your data in `NSData` and save it in `NSUserDefaults` and retrieved back, once needed. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917106/nsuserdefaults-unreliable-in-ios-8) thread and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html) one.

Comment: @Downvoter, please care to explain reason for down vote, i wouldn't give you a similar silent down vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Should not use NSUSerdefault to keep a collection of custom objects.
You should save them using NSkeyedUnarchiver/NSkeyedarchiver.
Ref: NSCoding.